# Bluemix monitoring and analytics liberty runtime

Tags: java, monitoring, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I am trying to use Bluemix monitoring and analytics service bounded to a java application running on Liberty runtime. But the service always shows application as unavailable (even though I can see and verify its working). And none of the stats on CPU/memory utilization & response/throughput times work. The application is started by calling the Main class and its NOT web application. Is there specific entry in manifest.yml for M&A to start working with the application. I have used M&A with node.js application and it worked well.

I thought I will just get an answer by simple google search but alas not able to find anything on this. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

The Monitoring & Analytics service generally assumes a web application. The availability tab is based on doing an http GET of your application's route as defined in Bluemix. Since yours is not a web application it presumably either doesn't have a route or doesn't respond to the one that it has if it does have one; this will cause M&A to report it as down.

Likewise for Liberty apps the performance data is gathered via Websphere application server JMX MBeans. If your app is not a web app, it is likely that it is invisible to these interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

There was a temporary outtage due to network issues, but things should be resolved now.  Restage your app and try again...